# How to get real time update from s3

Tags: logging, amazon-s3, websocket, kubernetes

Circleci and many other ci tools show real time logs during the job running.  It like the `tail -f` in linux but it also show all the previous logs.

I am trying to sync specific logs from kubernetes to s3 and then move the update to the browse it that possible?

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to sync specific logs from kubernetes to s3 and then move the update to the browse it that possible?

IMHO you would want to have a "tee" mechanism to divert the log streams to *each* destination, since those two destinations have vastly different access (and retry!) mechanisms. AFAIK kubernetes allows unlimited(?) numbers of `kubectl logs -f` connections, so you would want one process that connects to the pod and relays those bytes out to the browser, and a separate process that connects and relays the bytes to S3. You *could* have one process that does both, but that runs the risk of a single bug wiping out *both* streams, making everyone unhappy.

I used `kubectl logs -f` as a "shortcut" for this answer, but I am super positive there's an API endpoint for doing that, I just don't remember what it is offhand -- `kubectl --v=100 logs -f $pod` will show it to you.

Comment: So you mean I can just use `kubectl logs -f` in some way to send the result to the browser?

Comment: The short answer is yes; the long answer is that you'll almost certainly want to write a proxy between the browser and the kubernetes api so you don't expose the wild Internet to the api for your Pod (although, come to think of it, I guess with a **well written** RBAC policy, even that might be safe to do). You can see [how GitLab does it](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/v11.0.2/app/controllers/projects/environments_controller.rb#L117) for inspiration